# Compile time computing of number of bits needed to encode n different states

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time, constexpr, logarithm

*Edit:* In the initial question had a wrong formula and the algorithm tried was doing something completely different than what was intended. I apologise and I decided to rewrite the question to eliminate all the confusion.

I need to compute **at compile time** (the result will be used as a non-type template parameter) the minimum number of bits needed to store `n` different states:

```
constexpr unsigned bitsNeeded(unsigned n);
```

or via template

The results should be:

```
+-----------+--------+
| number of | bits   |
| states    | needed |
+-----------+--------+
|     0     |    0   | * or not defined
|           |        |
|     1     |    0   |
|           |        |
|     2     |    1   |
|           |        |
|     3     |    2   |
|     4     |    2   |
|           |        |
|     5     |    3   |
|     6     |    3   |
|     7     |    3   |
|     8     |    3   |
|           |        |
|     9     |    4   |
|    10     |    4   |
|    ..     |   ..   |
|    16     |    4   |
|           |        |
|    17     |    5   |
|    18     |    5   |
|    ..     |   ..   |
+-----------+--------+
```

---

The initial (somehow corrected) version for reference:

I need to compute **at compile time** (the result will be used as a non-type template parameter) the minimum number of bits needed to store `n` different states i.e. the integral part <del>(rounded down)</del> rounded up of binary logarithm:

[image: ceil(log2(n))]

```
constexpr unsigned ceilLog2(unsigned n);
```

This is what I came up with (**completely wrong**):

```
constexpr unsigned intLog2(unsigned num_states_) {
  return
    num_states_ == 1 ?
      1 :
      (
      intLog2(num_states_ - 1) * intLog2(num_states_ - 1) == num_states_ - 1 ?
        intLog2(num_states_ - 1) + 1 :
        intLog2(num_states_ - 1)
      );
}
```

<del>This produces the correct result</del> (for `num_states_ != 0`), but the recursion blows out exponentially and it is **practically unusable** for any input greater than 10 (the memory usage during compilation grows beyond 2GB, the OS freezes and the compiler crashes).

How can I compute this at compile time in a practical manner?

Comment: I can't believe that this produces correct results.

Comment: @Henrik it doesn't. `intLog2Runtime(256) = 16`, `intLog2Runtime(1024) = 32`.

Comment: @DanielKO [GCC 4.8 complains for 1024](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0517599d95d14504)...

Comment: Seems you're trying to compute the square root, not the logarithm.

Comment: The minimum number of bits would be the binary logarithm rounded up (not down).

Comment: @Henrik yes, I messed both the formula and the algorithm. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the confusion caused by the initial question I chose to post this answer. This is built upon the answers of @DanielKO and @Henrik.

The minimum number of bits needed to encode `n` different states:

```
constexpr unsigned bitsNeeded(unsigned n) {
  return n <= 1 ? 0 : 1 + bitsNeeded((n + 1) / 2);
}
```

Comment: This overflows for `n == UINT_MAX` which @DanielKO’s doesn’t.

Answer (score 13):

The minimum number of bits required to store `n` different states is `ceil(log2(n))`.

```
constexpr unsigned floorlog2(unsigned x)
{
    return x == 1 ? 0 : 1+floorlog2(x >> 1);
}

constexpr unsigned ceillog2(unsigned x)
{
    return x == 1 ? 0 : floorlog2(x - 1) + 1;
}
```

Note that `ceillog2(1) == 0`. This perfectly fine, because if you want to serialize an object, and you know that one of its data members can only take on the value `42`, you don't need to store anything for this member. Just assign `42` on deserialization.

Comment: @DanielKO looks like your compiler is broken. `ceillog2(2) == 1` http://ideone.com/6ztr7X

Comment: my mistake, I pasted the code incorrectly; I keep forgetting that middle-button pasting is unreliable in web-based text editors.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
constexpr unsigned numberOfBits(unsigned x)
{
    return x < 2 ? x : 1+numberOfBits(x >> 1);
}
```

Simpler expression, [correct result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecaece7d6b03b871).

**EDIT**: "correct result" as in "the proposed algorithm doesn't even come close"; of course, I'm computing the "number of bits to represent value x"; subtract 1 from the argument if you want to know how many bits to count from 0 to x-1. To represent 1024 you need 11 bits, to count from 0 to 1023 (1024 states) you need 10.

**EDIT 2**: renamed the function to avoid confusion.

Comment: Correct result? Are you sure?

Comment: yes, my algorithm was doing something completely different. I am sorry about that. What I am searching is the number of bits needed to store n different values, e.g. for n = 4 there are 2 bits needed. Your solution is very useful, thank you, easy to adapt to what I want. Again sorry for the very bad question.

Comment: again sorry for the confusion in the question. Your function is wrong when `x` is a power of 2. For instance for 8 states only 3 bits are needed. Your answer gives 4.

Comment: @bolov either you didn't read the ×edit×, or you didn't try to write 8 in binary (1000, that's 4 bits).

Comment: Suggest differing to @bolov's answer and deleting this one, it's too focused on the discussion...

Answer (score 4):

In C++20, we have (in the header `<bit>`):

```
template<class T>
  constexpr T log2p1(T x) noexcept;
```

*Returns:* If x == 0, 0; otherwise one plus the base-2 logarithm of x, with any fractional part discarded. 
*Remarks:* This function shall not participate in overload resolution unless T is an unsigned integer type.

Comment: I think it's called `std::bit_width()` [officially](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_width)

Comment: It is *now*; but it wasn't when I wrote that answer.

Answer (score 2):

maybe

```
constexpr int mylog(int n) {
    return (n<2) ?1:
           (n<4) ?2:
           (n<8) ?3:
           (n<16)?4:
           (n<32)?5:
           (n<64)?6:
           …
           ;
}
```

as you will use it as tempalte parameter you might want to check out what [boost has to offer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/log2.html)

Comment: yeah, I thought about this, I just hopped it wouldn't have to come to this.

Answer (score 1):

`constexpr` is a bit underpowered and will be until C++14. I recommend templates:

```
template<unsigned n> struct IntLog2;
template<> struct IntLog2<1> { enum { value = 1 }; };

template<unsigned n> struct IntLog2 {
private:
  typedef IntLog2<n - 1> p;
public:
  enum { value = p::value * p::value == n - 1 ? p::value + 1 : p::value };
};
```

Comment: **Why** do you suggest templates? The same is trivially possible with `constexpr`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: My hunch was that since templates have been used this way for longer than `constexpr`, the compiler might evaluate this 1:1 translation more quickly. I should have thought to change the algorithm, though, and I can understand if your objection is aesthetic.

Answer (score 1):

Something I've used in my own code:

```
static inline constexpr
uint_fast8_t log2ceil (uint32_t value)
/* Computes the ceiling of log_2(value) */
{
    if (value >= 2)
    {
        uint32_t mask = 0x80000000;
        uint_fast8_t result = 32;
        value = value - 1;

        while (mask != 0) {
            if (value & mask)
                return result;
            mask >>= 1;
            --result;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It requires C++14 to be used as `constexpr`, but it has the nice property that it's reasonably fast at run time—about an order of magnitude faster than using `std::log` and `std::ceil`—and I've verified that it produces the same results for all representable non-zero values (log is undefined on zero, though 0 is a reasonable result for this application; you don't need any bits to distinguish zero values) using the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include "log2ceil.hh"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    for (uint32_t i = 1; i; ++i)
    {
        // If auto is used, stupid things happen if std::uint_fast8_t
        // is a typedef for unsigned char
        int l2c_math = ceil (log (i) / log (2));
        int l2c_mine = log2ceil (i);
        if (l2c_mine != l2c_math)
        {
            cerr << "Incorrect result for " << i << ": cmath gives "
                 << l2c_math << "; mine gives " << l2c_mine << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    cout << "All results are as correct as those given by ceil/log." << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This shouldn't be too hard to generalize to different argument widths, either.